# C++: std::vector.push_back() и классы

Tags: c++, ооп, классы, vector

В своей программе я создал класс Score. В нем я создал пустой конструктор, а также конструктор, в котором передаваемая строка na по умолчанию равна *unknown*.

```
class Score{
    string name;
    int sc;

public:
    Score();
    Score(const int &sc, const string &na = "unknown"){
        this -> name = na;
        this -> sc = sc;
    }
};
```

Далее я хочу создать вектор объектов класса, который будет заполняться по мере считывания из специально заготовленного файла.

```
using namespace std;
int main(){
    ifstream F;
    string name;
    int score;
    vector<Score> v;

    F.open("score.txt");
    if( ( F.is_open() ) && ( !F.eof() ) ){
        F >> name;
        F >> score;
        v.push_back(score,name);
    }
    F.close();
return 0;
}
```

На данном этапе компилятор выдает ошибку -

```
<...>\main.cpp:60: error: no matching function for call to 'std::vector<Score>::push_back(int&, std::string&)'
         v.push_back(score,name);
                               ^
```

Искренне не понимаю, что я делаю не так и прошу помочь разобраться. Заранее благодарю.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нужно писать так `v.push_back(Score(score,name));`

Comment: Благодарю, все заработало!

Answer (score 8):

Используйте [emplace_back](http://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back) - это более лаконично и производительно. Тогда Вы сможете писать как писали изначально:

```
v.emplace_back(score, name);
```

Это будет работать только в режиме C++11 или C++14, но сейчас уже все основные компиляторы хорошо поддерживают эти стандарты (но пока не включат их по умолчанию, например g++ и clang++ требуют ключ -std=c++11).

Еще несколько замечаний:

- Вы ничего не потеряете, заменив `const int &` на `int` - даже наоборот
- Вашу проверку потока можно заменить просто на `if (F)` - там идет преобразование в `bool`, эквивалентное вызову `good()`
- Вместо `open` можно использовать просто конструктор `ifstream`, принимающий имя файла, а вызывать `close` вручную в этом примере вообще не обязательно, так как `F` тут же выходит из области видимости, и файл закроется в деструкторе
- <s>Менее очевидная доработка: если вы намерились копировать строку, передаваемую в конструктор, то наиболее эффективно передавать ее по значению, а в конструкторе переносить</s> со строками это плохая идея из-за small string optimization, и вообще подводных камней тут очень много, так что отзываю эту рекомендацию <_<

Смотрите книжки *Effective C++* и *Effective Modern C++* за подробностями